# The validator cannot currently accept more batches, due to a full queue. Please submit your request again

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am reading data from a CSV file and storing each record in Blockchain.
While uploading file having more than 150 records getting error:

> "The validator cannot currently accept more batches, due to a full
>   queue.  Please submit your request again."

Please help how can I resolve this issue.

Comment: How many transactions are there in your batch? You could add more transactions per batch.

Answer (score 0):

I think we have a few options. we could slow down your import script or wait for a valid block to be returned until inserting next row from csv. We could also look at submitting blocks of transactions in a single batch. Other than that not sure if the default queue length can be increased.

I am using timmer concept.

```
json.objects.forEach(function(obj,index,collection) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('foobar');
            self.insertDesignJsonObject(obj, index);
        }, index * 5000);
    });
```